# Creating table view controllers from data retrieved in View Did Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, viewdidload

Hi I am pretty new to creating Table View Controllers. I'm having difficulty trying to load data retrieved via Json in the ViewDidLoad section, into a table view controller.
The first thing I noticed is that the array where I eventually put my json data (dataArray) is not available in: numberOfRowsInSection, so I declared it outside viewDidLoad but now see that when I debug the array is empty when it gets to numberOfRowsInSection. I did test the retrieval code beforehand so am sure it works.
I have a couple of questions:
1. why is that dataArray is empty in the other methods?
2. is it fine to load data for displaying in tableviews in ViewDidLoad or should I really be loading this data somewhere else where it is more visible and available for use by the tableview methods?

Here is the code:

```
NSArray *dataArray = nil;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    //  Set URL variable with Token
    NSString *token = @"99fdf505547d607e65b8b8ff16113337";
    NSString *teacherUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://covle.com/apps/api/nextdoorteacher/teachers?t=%@",token];

    //  Set up the session configuration
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:teacherUrl]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"response ==> %@", response);

                if (!error) {
                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200){

                        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                        NSLog(@" heres the serialised json ===> %@", jsonData);
                        // move serialised JSON into Array (as the data contained is in array)
```

dataArray=(NSArray*)[jsonData copy];

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return dataArray.count;
    NSLog(@"Array count is set to ===> %@", dataArray.count);
```

Any help to understand and fix this would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this
`NSArray *dataArray=(NSArray*)[jsonData copy];`
You are creating a new local variable named dataArray which is NOT the same as the global dataArray which u allocated in viewDidLoad, so just write this
`dataArray = (NSArray*)[jsonData copy];` and you will get the array count as expected in `numberOfRowsInSection`

EDIT:
call `[self.tableview reloadData]` after `dataArray = (NSArray*)[jsonData copy]` for calling tableview delegate methods to fire once again!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer Saheb. I have changed this and did expect it to fix the issue, but there is still something that is stopping this from working. I added:                                                                                                          // move serialised JSON into Array (as the data contained is in array)
                        dataArray=(NSArray*)[jsonData copy];      but dataArray is still empty at numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: Plz edit your question as to what is the problem and what changes did u did.

Comment: if your tableview is not loading the values then check my answer edit

Comment: How should I add (tableview reloadData] currently I get errors if I try? So I tried as follows: [TeachersTableViewController reloadData]; but get error no known class method for reloadData.

Comment: If you are using a tableviewcontroller then check my edit `self.tableview reloadData` OR if you are using a normal View controller then there must be an outlet of the custom tableview so call `[myCustomTableviewName reloadData]`

Comment: I am using a tableviewcontroller and yes tried changing it to [self.tableView reloadData]; but still a nil value in dataArray at numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: the first time it will show a nill value as the JSON value has not arrived yet!
But once the json value is arrived, and u are assigning that value to your array at `dataArray = [jsonData copy]` and calling `[self.tableview reload]`
numberOfRowsInSection will again get called and this time around it will give you the desired value

Comment: Ok I understand it now. Thanks very much for the answers and patience Saheb Roy.